# Обособление оборота с "как" (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обороты-с-как

*Ты ведёшь себя со мною(,) как со всеми(,) или нет?*

Если обособить оборот и изъять его, получится *"ведёшь себя со мною или нет"* — как-то странно, поэтому не очень хочется его обособлять.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136031/discussion-on-question-by-------2).

Comment: Артем, ничего изымать здесь нельзя, но это ни о чем не говорит. Вы таким действием нарушаете и структуру, и семантику предложения. Подобная проверка мало что дает и эффективна только в частных случаях.  В вашем предложении семантически необходимым является всё сочетание «со мною, как со всеми», и его следует рассматривать как единое целое. Но при этом сочетание включает в себя обособленный сравнительный оборот.

Answer (score 2):

Именно в таком предложении запятая перед ***как*** совсем ни к чему. Логическое ударение падает на ***всеми***, ну и на ***нет***.

Я бы не стал ставить никаких запятых. Предложение читается в нормальном темпе с минимальной произносительной паузой перед ***или***, хотя можно обойтись и без неё.

Если уж автор всё-таки хочет выразить эту паузу, то пусть ставит запятую, да даже тире не будет лишним.

*Ты ведёшь себя со мною как со всеми, или нет?*
*Ты ведёшь себя со мною как со всеми – или нет?*

А ещё лучше для обозначения паузы подойдёт такой вариант:
*Ты ведёшь себя со мною как со всеми? Или нет?*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136030/discussion-on-answer-by-------2).

Answer (score 1):

Не обособляются обороты с союзом КАК

> Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав сказуемого и предложение без
> такого оборота не имеет законченного смысла, например: Она держится
> как хозяйка. (Грамота.ру)

http://www.gramota.tv/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/gramota/punct/338-45-183?

Answer (score 1):

Свой ответ я уже дала и обосновала в комментариях: ***Ты ведешь себя со мнОю, как со всЕми, или нет?***

Сравнительный оборот обособлен, поэтому обоснование второй запятой не требуется. А этот ответ посвящен особой теме.

**Тесная связь слов со сказуемым и лексическая недостаточность сказуемого – это одно и то же?**

1. **Приведу пример для сравнения.** Действие, которое обозначает **переходный глагол**, обязательно предполагает наличие объекта (прямого дополнения), который дополняет его семантику. Без такого объекта глагол лексически неполный. Можно сказать, что переходный глагол имеет незаполненную **лексическую валентность** на дополнение.

В то же время мы не считаем, что дополнение **входит в сказуемое** или тесно связано с ним. Такое дополнение не обязательно стоит после глагола, но может менять свою позицию. Другими словам, **«структурной валентности»** на определенную позицию дополнения здесь нет.

2. Устойчивое сочетание «вести себя» тоже **не требует обязательного порядка** слов и допускает их перестановку, например: «Медведя лет пяти-шести учили, как себя вести». Значит, «структурной валентности» здесь тоже нет, хотя сочетание неделимое (в его состав входят два вполне определенных слова).
3. Мы часто говорим о **тесной связи** слова со сказуемым и тогда не обособляем его. Цитирую: «*Без сравнительного оборота глагол «вести», да и всё сочетание, не выражает нужного смысла*».

Действительно, это сочетание требует **обязательного обстоятельства**, только тогда его лексика будет выраженной. Но это обстоятельство тоже можно переставить в другую позицию – оно «не привязано к сочетанию», просто обязательно должно присутствовать в предложении. Да и выразить его можно по-разному: Веди себя хорошо. Веди себя так, как нужно.

4. В нашем предложении необходимое обстоятельственное значение задает **оборот с союзом КАК.** Например: Т*ы ведешь себя со мнОю, как со всЕми? Ты ведешь себя со* *всЕми, как со мнОю*? Здесь **запятая**, скорее всего, нужна. Но ведь можно переставить слова: *Ты со мнОю ведешь себя,  как со  всЕми?*

В общем случае дополнение (со мною, со всеми и др.) этому сочетанию не требуется, но здесь оно **необходимо**. Поэтому делаем вывод: обстоятельственное значение задает всё сочетание «***со мнОю, как со всЕми***». И оно является семантически необходимым, хотя в предложении может занимать свободную позицию.

5. А вот «**структурная валентность»**, то есть позиция слов, задается именно в предложении. Если оно начинается так: «Ты ведешь себя…», то дальше должен следовать составной оборот «со мнОю, как со всЕми». Глагол присоединяет к себе дополнение «со мною» **для образования первой фразы**, а далее следует пауза и вторая часть предложения. Здесь уже действуют структурные, а не семантические законы, и они определяют нужную расстановку знаков.
6. **И вывод:** не следует объяснять отсутствие запятой лексической неполнотой сказуемого. Необходимое слово или словосочетание должно присутствовать в предложении, но оно не обязательно располагается сразу после сказуемого.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ** (примеры из Нацкорпуса **с обособлением оборота**)

Оказывается, что **обособление** оборота, "тесно связанного со сказуемым иди даже входящего в сказуемое", ― это не проблема. Таких примеров достаточно.

―  Вообще-то я человек серьезный,  ― насупил брови Куликов,  ― но **с тобой** мне хочется **вести себя**, **как мальчишка**. [Евгений Сухов. Делу конец ― сроку начало (2007)]

Все понимали, что собрал он их неспроста. Старались шутить, **вести себя, как обычно.** Не получалось. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

Сама **ведёт себя, как хочет,** и ты можешь **вести себя ― как хочешь**. [В. В. Лопатин. Кич // «Волга», 2014]

Но глаза мальчишки так горели, что он решил **не вести себя, как последний зануда.** [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136046/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----2).

Comment: Ничего не понял, но очень интересно. Добавлю вопрос в закладки, чтобы как-нибудь на свежую голову изучить сей эпос)

Comment: Это эпическая поэма, обязательно изучите :))  Иначе ваше образование в области русской грамматики нельзя считать состоявшимся.